# how to get a message from this Json

Tags: java, android, json, string, parsing

I listen to the socket and it comes Json, but I can’t parse it to get a message

```
[private-meeting-chat.98, 
{"success":true,"data":
{"message":"Fuhvvhjv",
"chat_message_type_id":1},
"socket":null}]
```

here is the code i use

```
privateChannel.listen("MeetingChatMessage", args -> {
            Log.i("Log", Arrays.toString(args));
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                try {
                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(args);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    JSONObject jsonDATA= jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
                    String message = jsonDATA.getString("message");

                    Log.i("Log", message);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
```

`args` comes to me, I can see it in the logs, but I can’t get information from it

Comment: You need to provide more information about `args` - what is its type? what is the structure?

Comment: [private-meeting-chat.99, {"success":true,"data":{"message":"Jdjdjd","chat_message_type_id":1},"socket":null}]

Comment: here is the structure of my answer, type Object

Comment: Is this is a list? or json string?

Comment: in the method it is given as an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, it seems that `args` is a list/array where the 2nd element is the response from the channel. So you need to access that element and convert to json.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(args[1]);
JSONObject jsonDATA= jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
String message = jsonDATA.getString("message");
```

Also, since it's not working, did you check what the error stacktrace is?

Comment: error: no suitable constructor found for JSONObject(Object) this error

Comment: JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(args[1]));   this work

Comment: What is the type of `args[1]`?

Comment: indicates to me that object

Comment: Perhaps, it's already JSONObject. If you read the docs for the lib that you are using, you would get more info. And perhaps, you won't need to convert it.